# How to generate vector objects from multiple selection on an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image in photoshop that contains multiple objects. I made a multiple selection of those objects (they all have the same color) Is it possible to transform the selection into multiple vector objects so i can resize all of them easily and get better result for small size. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably get better results in Illustrator with auto trace.

- Place your file in AI
- Highlight and choose live trace (IIRC).from the object menu
- Adjust the live trace settings until you get the paths you're after
- Expand the live trace (in the object menu) to get to the paths themselves

Comment: What would be the steps in Illustrator then?

Comment: Further detail added above.

Comment: I am sorry i don't know much in illustrator what do u mean by highlight - do u mean select? Also I see a live paint menu but no live trace are u referring to live paint?

Comment: ok i manage to get the expected result: i have just used image trace and expand. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I had in mind. http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/illustrator-tutorials/adobe-illustrator-tip-1-intro-and-livetrace/

Comment: I figured out Image trace is a new feature of illustrator cs6: http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-new-image-trace-in-adobe-illustrator-cs6/

Comment: Good to know. I haven't had a shot at 6 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to right-clicking your selection and then select "Make work path..".
Or you can convert the objects individually to the path and pack they to the smart object.